# non-adaptive width of the "Quill" library when used in chat

Tags: flutter, dart, quill

I encountered a problem when using the **"flutter_quill"** library. I use it in a chat and I need to make sure that the size of the container around the text matches the size of this text itself. That is, if the text is small, then the container is not wide; if the text is large, then the width is accordingly large. However, here's the thing: Quill has unlimited width, as if I were using **Expanded** on **Row**. If I set a fixed width, something like **width 200**, then regardless of the size of the text, the container around it will be exactly 200.

Perhaps some of you have encountered a similar problem and can help me.

Below I have attached a screenshot of what it looks like practically.

On top is the text in the Quill wrapper, on the bottom is plain text (***this is what the result I want looks like***)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjyzM.jpg)

I tried various ways to fix this problem.
Wrapped in Row, Container with fixed width and so on, found a way to achieve +- good results using **IntrinsicWidth**, but this option is not suitable because it is too expensive and leads to creating a layout of **O(N²)** size